# Modernizr.touch returns true on firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, modernizr, touch-event

I have written a peace of code to get the event based on touch and non-touch. Its working all other browsers and devices, but Firefox. Default FF return the `true`.

```
var thumbsEvent, isTouch = Modernizr.touch; // detect the touch
if(isTouch){
   thumbsEvent = 'click';//on touch surface, click
}
else {
   thumbsEvent = 'mouseover';//on non touch surface, mouseover
}
```

Is there a way to manage this issue.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/2H23B/)

Comment: Interesting. Returning false from here. FF 27 & Win 7.

Comment: @Bob Thanks, did you do any config changes to FF?

Comment: Nope. I did find this though that will probably interest you: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/920#issuecomment-17433197

Comment: Current version of FF for me says false

Comment: Your pattern here assumes “no touch” == “has mouse”, which won’t always be true. Keyboards can’t fire `mouseover` events, so a user who only has a keyboard wouldn’t be able to perform the interaction (e.g. open a menu). It’s commonly recommended to *always* bind `click` events, regardles of detection results, as that’s the ‘universal’ event which all input methods can fire one way or another. See [“The Golden Pattern”](http://www.stucox.com/blog/the-golden-pattern-for-handling-touch-input/) and [“Touch And Mouse”](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/).

Comment: Answer is below, but buried: `Modernizr.touchevents` has replaced `Modernizr.touch`

Answer (score 15):

On behalf of Modernizr - We're really sorry about this.

`Modernizr.touch` has been renamed `Modernizr.touchevents` in the yet-to-be-released version 3.0, as it is a far more accurate description of the detect. Basically, all this detect is doing is checking for the existence of touch events, and returning true if they are found. Desktop chrome does the same thing if you enable developer tools. It just means that your version of firefox on your laptop is reporting support of touch events, for several possible reasons.

Comment: `Modernizr.touchEvents` is undefined, but `Modernizr.touchevents` is boolean.

Comment: sorry about that. Modernizr is always lowercase

Comment: So, what is the solution to prevent it ?

Answer (score 4):

i had the same issue, this fixed it for me: in firefox go to "about:config", then search for the setting "dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled" and reset that one. i then had to restart firefox and afterwards "Modernizr.touch" correctly returned "false" for me.

source: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1225

Comment: added +1, but will this solve problem on customers Firefox browsers? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have same issue: Modernizr.touch returns true at desktop FireFox 33.1, Mac OS.

My solution: using mobile-first approach, apply all touch-related bells-and-whistles by default. If Modernizr detect .no-touch then apply (or disable) some site features for desktop users.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue some time ago.

The problem was that some laptop models come with a version with touchscreen. We found out that if one uses such a model, `Modernizr.touch` returns true even if this person is using the non-touch laptop model version.

Now, click-events do work on touch devices, but not the other way round. So we worked around this limitation by adding an additional check:

```
var thumbsEvent, isTouch = Modernizr.touch;
var isAndroid = ...; // Android detection code
var isIOs = ...; // iOS detection code

// touch is only supported on iOS and Android
// devices, which have for sure a touch interface
if(isTouch && (isAndroid || isIOs) ){
    thumbsEvent = 'click';
}
else {
    thumbsEvent = 'mouseover';
}
```

That's probably not an optimal solution, because you need to do the device detection with user-agent sniffing instead of feature detection, which was probably why you used Modernizr in the first place.

Also, devices which support touch but are neither iOS nor Android will be excluded from  touch events.

Answer (score 1):

There is a temporary fix to this. I was having the same problem so what i did was i did a little digging to find an html5 property which gets detected by FF but not on mobile devices and i found flexbox to be one of them. (Read: http://html5please.com/#flexbox). 
So below is the code you can use to have your problem fixed:

```
var isTouch = Modernizr.touch, // detect the touch
    isFlex = Modernizr.flexbox; // detect flexbox

if (isTouch) {
    // Detect if FF
    if (isFlex) ) {
       thumbsEvent = 'mouseover'; //on FF, mouseover
    } else {
       thumbsEvent = 'click';//on non-FF touch surface, click
    }
} else {
   thumbsEvent = 'mouseover';//on non touch surface, mouseover
}
```

Please do note that this is temporary, if mobile devices start supporting flexbox it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a know Firefox Bug at least since FF27: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=970346