# How to identify if a mouseover event object came from a touchscreen touch?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, touch, raphael

On virtually all current browsers  (extensive [details from patrickhlauke on github](https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/results/), which [I summarised in an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39477086/568458), and also some more info [from QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html)), touchscreen touches trigger `mouseover` events (sometimes creating an invisible pseudo-cursor that stays where the user touched until they touch elsewhere).

Sometimes this causes undesirable behaviour in cases where touch/click and mouseover are intended to do different things.

From inside a function responding to a mouseover event, that has been passed the `event` object, is there any way I can check if this was a "real" mouseover from a moving cursor that moved from outside an element to inside it, or if it was caused by this touchscreen behaviour from a touchscreen touch?

The `event` object looks identical. For example, on chrome, a mouseover event caused by a user touching a touchscreen has `type: "mouseover"` and nothing I can see that would identify it as touch related.

I had the idea of binding an event to `touchstart` that alters mouseover events then an event to `touchend` that removes this alteration. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because the event order appears to be `touchstart` → `touchend` → `mouseover` → `click` (I can't attach the normalise-mouseover function to click without messing up other functionality).

---

I'd expected this question to have been asked before but existing questions don't quite cut it:

- [How to handle mouseover and mouseleave events in Windows 8.1 Touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059800/how-to-handle-mouseover-and-mouseleave-events-in-windows-8-1-touchscreen) is about C# / ASP.Net applications on Windows, not web pages in a browser
- [JQuery .on(“click”) triggers “mouseover” on touch device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403733/jquery-onclick-triggers-mouseover-on-touch-device) is similar but is about jQuery and the answer is a bad approach (guessing a hard-coded list of touchscreen user agents, which would break when new device UAs are created, and which falsely assumes all devices are mouse *or* touchscreen)
- [Preventing touch from generating mouseOver and mouseMove events in Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665855/preventing-touch-from-generating-mouseover-and-mousemove-events-in-android-brows) is the closest I could find, but it is only about Android, is about preventing not identifying mouseover on touch, and has no answer
- [Browser handling mouseover event for touch devices causes wrong click event to fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446539/browser-handling-mouseover-event-for-touch-devices-causes-wrong-click-event-to-f) is related, but they're trying to elumate the iOS two-tap interaction pattern, and also the only answer makes that mistake of assuming that touches and mouse/clicks are mutually exclusive.

The best I can think of is to have a touch event that sets some globally accessible variable flag like, say, `window.touchedRecently = true;` on `touchstart` but not click, then removes this flag after, say, a 500ms `setTimeout`. This is an ugly hack though.

---

Note - we *cannot* assume that touchscreen devices have no mouse-like roving cursor or visa versa, because there are many devices that use a touchscreen and mouse-like pen that moves a cursor while hovering near the screen, or that use a touchscreen and a mouse (e.g. touchscreen laptops). More details in my answer to [How do I detect whether a browser supports mouseover events?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39474891/568458).

Note #2 - this is *not* a jQuery question, my events are coming from Raphael.js paths for which jQuery isn't an option and which give a plain vanilla browser `event` object. If there is a Raphael-specific solution I'd accept that, but it's very unlikely and a raw-javascript solution would be better.

Comment: Found this on a Google quest for the same solution, having already devoured Patrick's _superb_ research. Current answers are _awful_ given the quality & clarity of this question, bounty hunters wanted. For the time being, my friend found this [excellent Google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-ZUtS3knhJP4RbWC74fUZbNp6cbytG6Wen7hewdCtdo) off the back of this [article on input device capabilities](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/inputdevicecapabilities)

Answer (score 15):

Given the complexity of the issue, I thought it was worth detailing the issues and edge cases involved in any potential solution.

**The issues:**

***1 - Different implementations of touch events across devices and browsers***. What works for some will definitely not work for others. You only need to glance at those [patrickhlauke](https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/results/) resources to get an idea of how differently the process of tapping a touch-screen is currently handled across devices and browsers.

***2 - The event handler gives no clue as to its initial trigger.*** You are also absolutely right in saying that the `event` object is identical (certainly in the vast majority of cases) between mouse events dispatched by interaction with a mouse, and mouse events dispatched by a touch interaction.

***3 - Any solution to this problem which covers all devices could well be short-lived*** as the current W3C Recommendations do not go into enough detail on how touch/click events should be handled (https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/), so browsers will continue to have different implementations. It also appears that the Touch Events standards document has not changed in the past 5 years, so this isn't going to fix itself soon. https://www.w3.org/standards/history/touch-events

***4 - Ideally, solutions should not use timeouts*** as there is no defined time from touch event to mouse event, and given the spec, there most probably won't be any time soon. Unfortunately, timeouts are almost inevitable as I will explain later.

---

**A future solution:**

***In the future, the solution will probably be to use*** `Pointer Events` instead of mouse / touch events as these give us the `pointerType` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events), but unfortunately we're not there yet in terms of an established standard, and so cross-browser compatibility (https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer%20events) is poor.

---

**How do we solve this at the moment**

If we accept that:

1. You can't detect a touchscreen (http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/)
2. Even if we could, there's still the issue of non-touch events on a touch capable screen

Then we can only use data about the mouse event itself to determine its origin. As we've established, the browser doesn't provide this, so we need to add it ourselves. The only way to do this is using the touch events which are triggered around the same time as the mouse event.

Looking at the [patrickhlauke](https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/results/) resources again, we can make some statements:

1. `mouseover` is always followed by the click events `mousedown` `mouseup` and `click` - always in that order. (Sometimes separated by other events). This is backed up by the W3C recommendations: https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/.
2. For most devices / browsers, the `mouseover` event is always preceded by either `pointerover`, its MS counterpart `MSPointerOver`, or `touchstart`
3. The devices / browsers whose event order begins with `mouseover` have to be ignored. We can't establish that the mouse event was triggered by a touch event *before* the touch event itself has been triggered.

---

Given this, we could set a flag during `pointerover`, `MSPointerOver`, and `touchstart`, and remove it during one of the click events. This would work well, except for a handfull of cases:

1. `event.preventDefault` is called on one of the touch events - the flag will never be unset as the click events will not be called, and so any future genuine click events on this element would still be marked as a touch event
2. if the target element is moved during the event. The W3C Recommendations state

> If the contents of the document have changed during processing of the
>   touch events, then the user agent may dispatch the mouse events to a
>   different target than the touch events.

---

Unfortunately this means  that we will always need to use timeouts. To my knowledge there is no way of either establishing when a touch event has called `event.preventDefault`, nor understanding when the touch element has been moved within the DOM and the click event triggered on another element.

I think this is a fascinating scenario, so this answer will be amended shortly to contain a recommended code response. For now, I would recommend the answer provided by @ibowankenobi or the answer provided by @Manuel Otto.

Answer (score 8):

What we do know is:

**When the user uses no mouse**

- the `mouseover` is directly (within 800ms) fired after either a `touchend` or a
  `touchstart` (if the user tapped and held).
- the position of the `mouseover` and the `touchstart`/`touchend` are identical.

**When the user uses a mouse/pen**

- The `mouseover` is fired before the touch events, even if not, the position of the `mouseover` will not match the touch events' position 99% of time.

Keeping these points in mind, I made a snippet, which will add a flag `triggeredByTouch = true` to the event if the listed conditions are met. Additionally you can add this behaviour to other mouse events or set `kill = true` in order to discard mouseevents triggered by touch completely.

```
(function (target){
    var keep_ms = 1000 // how long to keep the touchevents
    var kill = false // wether to kill any mouse events triggered by touch
    var touchpoints = []

    function registerTouch(e){
        var touch = e.touches[0] || e.changedTouches[0]
        var point = {x:touch.pageX,y:touch.pageY}
        touchpoints.push(point)
        setTimeout(function (){
            // remove touchpoint from list after keep_ms
            touchpoints.splice(touchpoints.indexOf(point),1)
        },keep_ms)
    }

    function handleMouseEvent(e){
        for(var i in touchpoints){
            //check if mouseevent's position is (almost) identical to any previously registered touch events' positions
            if(Math.abs(touchpoints[i].x-e.pageX)<2 && Math.abs(touchpoints[i].y-e.pageY)<2){
                //set flag on event
                e.triggeredByTouch = true
                //if wanted, kill the event
                if(kill){
                    e.cancel = true
                    e.returnValue = false
                    e.cancelBubble = true
                    e.preventDefault()
                    e.stopPropagation()
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }

    target.addEventListener('touchstart',registerTouch,true)
    target.addEventListener('touchend',registerTouch,true)

    // which mouse events to monitor
    target.addEventListener('mouseover',handleMouseEvent,true)
    //target.addEventListener('click',handleMouseEvent,true) - uncomment or add others if wanted
})(document)
```

**Try it out:**

```js
function onMouseOver(e){
  console.log('triggered by touch:',e.triggeredByTouch ? 'yes' : 'no')
}



(function (target){
 var keep_ms = 1000 // how long to keep the touchevents
 var kill = false // wether to kill any mouse events triggered by touch
 var touchpoints = []

 function registerTouch(e){
  var touch = e.touches[0] || e.changedTouches[0]
  var point = {x:touch.pageX,y:touch.pageY}
  touchpoints.push(point)
  setTimeout(function (){
   // remove touchpoint from list after keep_ms
   touchpoints.splice(touchpoints.indexOf(point),1)
  },keep_ms)
 }

 function handleMouseEvent(e){
  for(var i in touchpoints){
   //check if mouseevent's position is (almost) identical to any previously registered touch events' positions
   if(Math.abs(touchpoints[i].x-e.pageX)<2 && Math.abs(touchpoints[i].y-e.pageY)<2){
    //set flag on event
    e.triggeredByTouch = true
    //if wanted, kill the event
    if(kill){
     e.cancel = true
     e.returnValue = false
     e.cancelBubble = true
     e.preventDefault()
     e.stopPropagation()
    }
    return
   }
  }
 }

 target.addEventListener('touchstart',registerTouch,true)
 target.addEventListener('touchend',registerTouch,true)

 // which mouse events to monitor
 target.addEventListener('mouseover',handleMouseEvent,true)
 //target.addEventListener('click',handleMouseEvent,true) - uncomment or add others if wanted
})(document)
```

```css
a{
  font-family: Helvatica, Arial;
  font-size: 21pt;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="onMouseOver(event)">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

According to https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/

For a single click the order of events is:

1. touchstart
2. touchmove
3. touchend
4. mouseover
5. mousemove
6. mousedown
7. mouseup
8. click

So you might be able to set some arbitrary boolean `isFromTouchEvent = true;` in onTouchStart() and `isFromTouchEvent = false;` in onClick() and check for that inside of onMouseOver(). This doesn't work very well since we're not guaranteed to get all those events in the element that we're trying to listen on.

Answer (score 3):

I usually have couple of general schemes which I use for this, one of them uses a manual principle of setTimeout to trigger a property. I will explain this one here, but first try to reason about using touchstart, touchmove and touchend on touch devices and use mouseover on destop.

As you know, calling event.preventDefault (event has to be not passive for this to work with touchstart) in any of the touchevents will cancel the subsequent mousecalls so you do not need to deal with them. But in case this is not what you want, here is what I use sometimes (I refer as "library" to your dom manipulation library, and "elem" as your element):

### with setTimeout

```
library.select(elem) //select the element
.property("_detectTouch",function(){//add  a _detectTouch method that will set a property on the element for an arbitrary time
    return function(){
        this._touchDetected = true;
        clearTimeout(this._timeout);
        this._timeout = setTimeout(function(self){
            self._touchDetected = false;//set this accordingly, I deal with either touch or desktop so I can make this 10000. Otherwise make it ~400ms. (iOS mouse emulation delay is around 300ms)
        },10000,this);
    }
}).on("click",function(){
    /*some action*/
}).on("mouseover",function(){
    if (this._touchDetected) {
        /*coming from touch device*/
    } else {
        /*desktop*/
    }
}).on("touchstart",function(){
    this._detectTouch();//the property method as described at the beginning
    toggleClass(document.body,"lock-scroll",true);//disable scroll on body by overflow-y hidden;
}).on("touchmove",function(){
    disableScroll();//if the above overflow-y hidden don't work, another function to disable scroll on iOS.
}).on("touchend",function(){
    library.event.preventDefault();//now we call this, if you do this on touchstart chrome will complain (unless not passive)
    this._detectTouch();
    var touchObj = library.event.tagetTouches && library.event.tagetTouches.length 
        ? library.event.tagetTouches[0] 
        : library.event.changedTouches[0];
    if (elem.contains(document.elementFromPoint(touchObj.clientX,touchObj.clientY))) {//check if we are still on the element.
        this.click();//click will never be fired since default prevented, so we call it here. Alternatively add the same function ref to this event.
    }
    toggleClass(document.body,"lock-scroll",false);//enable scroll
    enableScroll();//enableScroll
})
```

Another option without setTimeout is to think mousover is counter to touchstart and mouseout counter to touchend. So former events (the touch events) will set a property, if the mouse events detect that property then they do not fire and reset the property to its initial value and so on. In that case something along these lines will  also do:

### without setTimeout

```
....
.on("mouseover",function(dd,ii){
                    if (this._touchStarted) {//touch device
                        this._touchStarted = false;//set it back to false, so that next round it can fire incase touch is not detected.
                        return;
                    }
                    /*desktop*/
                })
                .on("mouseout",function(dd,ii){//same as above
                    if(this._touchEnded){
                        this._touchEnded = false;
                        return;
                    }
                })
                .on("touchstart",function(dd,ii){
                    this._touchStarted = true;
                    /*some action*/
                })
                .on("touchend",function(dd,ii){
                    library.event.preventDefault();//at this point emulations should not fire at all, but incase they do, we have the attached properties
                    this._touchEnded = true;
                    /*some action*/
                });
```

I removed a lot of details but I guess this is the main idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use modernizr for that! I just tested this on a local development server and it works.

```
if (Modernizr.touch) { 
  console.log('Touch Screen');
} else { 
  console.log('No Touch Screen');
}
```

So I would start there?

Comment: Sadly it's not that simple, see the first note at the end of the question. "Device has touchscreen" !== "Mouseover events came from touch", there are plenty of devices with both touchscreens and normal mouse-like input. Also, several desktop browsers report true for `Modernizr.touch` even if the user's configuration doesn't currently include a touchscreen (see Modernizr's own answer on [Modernizr.touch returns true on firefox browser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22086292/568458)

Answer (score 1):

[Pointer Events are widely supported now](https://caniuse.com/?search=pointer%20events). So now we can use `pointerenter` and check `event.pointerType`:

```js
const element = document.getElementById("hoverableElement")

element.addEventListener("pointerenter", (event) => {
  if (event.pointerType === "mouse") {
    alert("Hovered")
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="hoverableElement">Trigger on hover, but not on touch</div>
```